# Mark calendar from access DB

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, calendar, oledb

Hy to all,

am having an issue trying to bind or connect the calendar with the database.
The app(access DB) is constantly updating with new dates, and every time the user login i need to display the dates from the DB to the calendar.
First of all am new at C# and am creating simple apps for work.
I have created a query that populate a datagrid (so the admin can manipulate) but cant find the way to fill selected dates in the calendar.

```
        try
        {
        string ID = labelIDFT.Content.ToString();
        string Query = "SELECT Ferie.Data FROM Ferie WHERE (Ferie.Login LIKE '%"+ ID +"%')";
        OleDbCommand cmnd = new OleDbCommand(Query, ConFerie);
        ConFerie.Open();
        cmnd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmnd);
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(tbl);
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = tbl.DefaultView;
        ConFerie.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ConFerie.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("A handled exception just occurred: " + ex.Message, "Exception Sample", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
    </i>
```

I tried creating a DataSet but i dont know how to bind to the calendar.
Anyone can help me?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Find myself an answer:

```
        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                DateTime TaskStart = DateTime.Parse(dr["Data"].ToString());
                TaskStart.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
                MonthlyCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(TaskStart);

            }
        }
```

It select the dates from the dataset
Thx anyway to all!!!